# Color for JFrame not working even though getcontentpane is already added

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am pretty new to Java. This is my class homework. I finished everything except the JFrame color doesn't show. I looked at all the other similar questions. Most of them said to use getContentPane(). The problem is I added that already but it is not showing. Below is my code. I separated it into two parts. The second part has all those JFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(color.**) code. Thank you.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class NumberGame extends JFrame  {

private JPanel Content;
private JFrame  DisplayFrame;
private JTextField Input;
private JLabel DisplayText, Message;
private int Guess;
private JButton button;
private JButton NewGame;
private int Number;
private int Lowest = 0;
private int Highest = 0;






  public  void NumberGame  () {
     Content = new JPanel ();
    DisplayFrame = new JFrame ("Welcome");
    DisplayFrame.setSize(700, 400);
    DisplayFrame.setLayout (new BorderLayout());

     DisplayText = new JLabel ("I have a number between 1 and 1000. Can you guess my number?    
 Enter your first guess.");





     Input = new JTextField (20);

     Content.add(Input);
     Message = new JLabel ("");

      button = new JButton ("Submit");
      button.addActionListener (new GuessHandler()); 





      NewGame = new JButton ("New Game");   
      NewGame.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
          public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) {
              Input.setText("");
              Message.setText("");
              repaint();
          }
        } );




    DisplayFrame.add(Content);
    Content.add(DisplayText);
    Content.add(Input);
    Content.add(button);
    Content.add(NewGame);
    Content.add(Message);


    theGame();
    DisplayFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

   public void theGame () {
       Number = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 +1);
   }








   public static void main(String[] args) {


    NumberGame a = new NumberGame ();
    a.NumberGame();



    }
```

Here is the rest of the code that I have problem with.

```
class GuessHandler implements ActionListener {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) {

       Guess = Integer.parseInt(Input.getText());

       if(Guess>Number) {
           Message.setText("Too high!");

           if (Guess < Lowest) {
               Lowest = Guess;
               DisplayFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);

           }

           else
               DisplayFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);
       }

       else if (Guess < Number) {
           Message.setText("Too Low!");

           if (Guess > Highest) {
               Highest = Guess;
               DisplayFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
           }
           else
               DisplayFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);
       }

       else {
           Message.setText("Correct!");
           Input.setEditable(false);
           Lowest = 0;
           Highest = 1000;
       }
           repaint ();


       }


   }

}
```

Comment: Please establish the habit of using lower case letters at the start of variable names.  In three years, your future self will thank you.

Comment: Sure. I will definitely start doing that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Content` is a `JPanel`, because `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout`, the panel `Content` will occupy the entire available space, covering the frames own content pane (don't confuse the two, the are different).

Try changing

```
DisplayFrame.add(Content);
```

to

```
DisplayFrame.setContentPane(Content);
```

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: It worked. But once it changed color, even when I press the NewGame button, it won't change the color back. It still stays the same. Doesn't repaint supposed to do that?

Comment: Sure, `repaint` will `repaint` the **current** state of the component, but you've not changed it...try setting the background color to `null` (it's a neat trick, but this forces the component to reset to it's default background color)